# Why is my histogram graph not showing any bars?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a histogram from the sum of 10 random variables extracted from 'rbinom(10, 10, 0.1)' simulated 5 times but the histogram would not show any bars or it would show only one..
How could I fix this?

```
Plot <- function(n1, size, p) {
  mean = c()
  set.seed(1234)
  v = rbinom(n1, size, p)
  repeats = 5
  for (i in 1:repeats) {
    k = mean(v)
    mean1 = c(mean, k)
    hist(mean1, main="n=5")
  }
}
```

Here is my code.

Comment: Are you looking for `hist(v)` or `barplot(a)` instead of `hist(a)`? It doesn't make sense to try to create a histogram from a length-two vector.

Comment: I get two bars, sometimes only one, although you probably don't want a histogram for data summaries.

Comment: You have a loop that is supposed to generate 5 histograms, but you call it without saving them or waiting for the user to see them, so your first four histograms flash out of existence and disappear. What are you hoping to get out of this? If you can't get _one_ hist/barplot to look like you want, then let's not talk about repeating it multiple times. Once that is resolved, then let's discuss what you want from _five_ consecutive plots (in one call to your `Plot(.)`). Perhaps also meaningful: what are you trying to demonstrate here?